# JUnit mocking method call

Tags: junit, mockito

I am writing a Junit test for a method '`methodA`' which is in class '`classA`'. In '`methodA`' another method '`methodB`' of class '`classB`' is called. The '`methodB`' calls soap web-service. I want to mock this `methodB` soap web-service call. In this case i am calling `classA.methodA`. Here i don't find a way that at the time when `classB.methodB` is called then mock value should get updated. I went through many links about `Mockito`, but they all refer on updating the mock value from `junit` class only. So, how can i pass mocked value their.

```
@Test
public void junitTest() {
 String arg1 = "arg1";
 classA aObj = new classA();
 aObj.methodA(arg1);
}

public classA {
 public string methodA(String arg1) {
  classB bObj = new classB();
  bObj.methodB();
  //somwthing on arg1
  return result;
 }
}

public classB {
 public list methodB() {
  //web-service call
  return list from web - service.
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please check [FAQs on **Asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a Junit test for a method `methodA` which is in class
>   `classA`

Since you are unit testing `methodA` of `classA`, you should be focusing on mocking just the `bObj.methodB();` call. You should not get into what it does or doesn't internally.

Not you are creating `classB` object in `methodA` which is not the ideal scenario. You should make `bObj` as the instance variable of `classA` with appropriate getter, setters and constructor.

Then from you testing class set this `classB` dependency.

You should structure your code and something tests like this:

```
class classAMicroTest {
    @Test
    public void junitTest() {
        String arg1 = "arg1";
        classA aObj = new classA();

        classB mockedBobj = Mockito.mock(classB.class);
        Mockito.when(mockedBobj.methodB()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
        aObj.setbObj(mockedBobj);

        aObj.methodA(arg1);

        Mockito.verify(mockedBobj, times(1)).methodB());
    }

}

class classA {

    classB bObj;

    public void setbObj(classB bObj) {
        this.bObj = bObj;
    }

    public String methodA(String arg1) {
        bObj.methodB();
        // somwthing on arg1
        return result;
    }

}

class classB {

    public List<String> methodB() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shanu Gupta